# Laravel 'join on' where two values are within 'x' of each other

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a MySQL query where I join on two values when they are +/- '3' of each other:

```
...
inner join 
on ABS(i.direction - i2.MWD) < 3 
and ABS(i.direction - i2.MWD) < 3
```

(I'm not entirely sure why the 'and' statement is exactly the same, but that's what made it work)

I've tried converting this to Eloquent using both

```
$join->on('i.direction', '-', 'i2.MWD', '<' 3)
```

and

```
$join->on('i.direction', '=', 'i2.MWD')
  ->where('i.direction', '-', 'i2.MWD', '<' 3)
```

The above two examples give me an empty result.  If I change the '<' to '>' in either example, I get all the joined data from both tables.

I've also tried using DB::raw as a workaround:

```
$join->on(DB::raw('ABS(input.direction - i2.MWD) < 3 
and ABS(input.direction - i2.MWD) < 3'));
```

which gives me the below error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'on clause' 
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate 
from (select * from `input` 
inner join 
 (select MWD, SWH, SWP, BUOY,Time from stations order by Time desc limit 4) 
  as i2 on ABS(input.direction - i2.MWD) < 3 
  and ABS(input.direction - i2.MWD) < 3 = ``) count_row_table)
```

(the trailing = '' which is being inserted after the 'i2.MWD) < 3' is confusing me).

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me come up with a solution for joining on the two values i.direction & i2.MWD (plus or minus 3) using Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

What you was trying to do here:

```
->where('i.direction', '-', 'i2.MWD', '<' 3)
```

you have to change for a raw where like this:

```
->whereRaw('i.direction - i2.MWD < ?', [3])
```

This should helps.

Comment: I tried as you suggested: ($join->on('i.direction', '=', 'i2.MWD')->whereRaw('i.direction - i2.MWD < ?', [3]);     but I am still only getting results where 'i.direction' is an exact match of 'i2.MWD'.  It appears the join statement is only matching the first criteria and not making it to the 'whereRaw' statement.